# Indentation Level error

Tags: python

I went through this code and eliminated all the tabs, replaced with spaces. I keep getting 
File "xxxx", line 14 except:
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Can anybody see any other problems?

```
### colorize_svg.py

import csv
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# Read in unemployment rates
unemployment = {}
min_value = 100; max_value = 0
reader = csv.reader(open('unemployment09.csv'), delimiter=",")
for row in reader:
        try:
            full_fips=row[1]+row[2]
            rate=float(row[8].strip())
            unemployment[full_fips]=rate
        except:
            pass


# Load the SVG map
svg = open('counties.svg', 'r').read()

# Load into Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, selfClosingTags=['defs','sodipodi:namedview'])

# Find counties
paths = soup.findAll('path')

# Map colors
colors = ["#D73027", "#FC8D59", "#FEE090", "#E0F3F8", "#91BFDB", "#4575B4"]

    # County style
    path_style = 'font-size:12px;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-opacity:1; stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel;fill:'



# Color the counties based on unemployment rate
for p in paths:

    if p['id'] not in ["State_Lines", "separator"]:
        # pass
        try:
            rate = unemployment[p['id']]
        except:
            continue

        if rate > 10:
            color_class = 5
        elif rate > 8:
            color_class = 4
        elif rate > 6:
            color_class = 3
        elif rate > 4:
            color_class = 2
        elif rate > 2:
            color_class = 1
        else:
            color_class = 0


        color = colors[color_class]
        p['style'] = path_style + color

print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: I see `path_style = ...` hanging out indented when it shouldn't be, just after `colors = [...`

Comment: Looks like it's the `except:` line near the top of the script.  @user1568778:  are you sure all tabs have been converted to spaces, in particular surrounding that `except:`?

Comment: If you got an indentation error then there is an indentation error. Nothing else is relevant and indentation errors are usually impossible to see when pasted into SO.

Comment: my suggestions, just highlight your whole code, and untabbify everything (in idle thats "ctrl+[" ) and then tabify them again.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

Your first for loop seems to have an extra identation level on the body, but this *could* be a problem with the copy/paste.

And:

```
# Find counties
paths = soup.findAll('path')

# Map colors
colors = ["#D73027", "#FC8D59", "#FEE090", "#E0F3F8", "#91BFDB", "#4575B4"]

    # County style
    path_style = 'font-size:12px;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-opacity:1; stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel;fill:'
```

As you can see here, path_style should be aligned with colors. That's probably where your error is.

Comment: Sorry, that indentation on the Path_style was my error when inputting the code into the question... I have 8 spaces in front of those lines instead of 4.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that your indentation error is the result of not replacing every tab with spaces.  It's certainly happened to me often enough - just go through again and confirm that there are no tabs left.

Answer (score 1):

When I paste your code into Python, it only brings up one IndentationError - at:

```
    # County style
    path_style = 'font-size:12px;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-opacity:1; stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel;fill:'
```

Which should not be indented, and so gives a slightly different error to the one you're seeing ("unexpected indent").

This means that the IndentationError you are seeing must be caused by a mix of tabs and spaces, which won't be maintained when copying and pasting between your code and StackOverflow. Line 14 is the `except:` in the top for loop - you will find that it and the `try` associated with it have a different combination of tabs and spaces.

The are various fixes to this - for example, you could remove the indentation from the front of the `try:` and `except:` both and replace with uniform indentation (hit tab once for both of them, having made sure you have tabs-to-spaces set or unset to match the style used in the rest of the file). But the easier way would be to just copy and paste the code from your question back into the .py file.

Comment: Sorry, that indentation on the Path_style was my error when inputting the code into the question... I have 8 spaces in front of those lines instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code in an editor which allows you to view hidden spaces and tabs.  Mixing up tabs and spaces has caused me many issues like this - stick to one form of indenting only.